# I am experiencing an error with one of my oracle stored procedures with error ORA:24344

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am experiencing an error with one of my oracle stored procedures with error ORA:24344 when trying to create a  stored procedure
I am getting the following error message 
     ORA-24344: success with compilation error
        PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
          PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_comms_update_stg (
ssms_key            IN VARCHAR2,
spolicyNumber       IN VARCHAR2,
sclientKey          IN VARCHAR2,
sclientReference    IN VARCHAR2,
sresult          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE stg_update_email 
  SET
   sms_key := ssms_key, 
  policy_number := spolicyNumber, 
  client_key := sclientKey, 
  process_status := 'Processed'
   WHERE client_reference = sclientReference;

    INSERT INTO EVENTLOG VALUES(seq_eventlog.NEXTVAL, spolicyNumber , (select 
   to_date(sysdate) from dual),
   to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS'), 101, null, 1, 'Updated stg_update_email', 
   'stg_update_email successfully updated', 'P', var_Client, null, null);


  sresult:= true;

  COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS Then
   Rollback;
   sresult := false;
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'ERROR IN EXECUTING PROCEDURE 
SP_UNDEL_UPD_STG - '|| chr(13)||chr(10) || UPPER(SQLERRM) || 
chr(13)||chr(10));
 END;
```

Comment: As an aside, `sresult` has a datatype of `sys_refcursor`; why are you trying to define it as true or false? Perhaps you meant it to be of `boolean` datatype? Also, sysdate is already of `date` datatype - don't use `to_date()` on it. If you want to truncate the date to midnight, use `trunc()`.

Comment: SQL in PL/SQL is still SQL. So you need to use the SQL assignment operator in the UPDATE statement, which is `=` not `:=`

Comment: after replacing := with = I am still getting the error and removingn the extra to_date()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments; fixing these issues should make your procedure compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_comms_update_stg(
                                                ssms_key            IN     VARCHAR2,
                                                spolicyNumber       IN     VARCHAR2,
                                                sclientKey          IN     VARCHAR2,
                                                sclientReference    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                                sresult                OUT boolean      /* based on your code, you probably need a BOOLEAN */
                                               ) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE stg_update_email
       SET sms_key           = ssms_key,        /* = and not := */
           policy_number     = spolicyNumber,   /* = and not := */
           client_key        = sclientKey,      /* = and not := */
           process_status    = 'Processed'      /* = and not := */
     WHERE client_reference  = sclientReference;

    INSERT INTO EVENTLOG
         VALUES (
                 seq_eventlog.NEXTVAL,
                 spolicyNumber,
                 sysdate,    --(SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL),     /* let's simplify! also, to_date(sysdate) makes no sense: sysdate already is a date */
                 /* or even trunc(sysdate) if you don't want time informations*/
                 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
                 101,
                 NULL,
                 1,
                 'Updated stg_update_email',
                 'stg_update_email successfully updated',
                 'P',
                 var_Client,                    /* where is var_Client defined ? */
                 NULL,
                 NULL
                );


    sresult    := TRUE;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        sresult    := FALSE;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'ERROR IN EXECUTING PROCEDURE SP_UNDEL_UPD_STG - '
            || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || UPPER(SQLERRM) || CHR(13) || CHR(10));
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksej , I was missing var_client actual value , Its now working !

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00927: missing equal sign
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

That was pointing out that you had used the PL/SQL assignment operator `:=` instead of the SQL one `=` in your update statement. But you say despite having fixed that you still cannot compile your procedure. Maybe it's just that the compiler doesn't like assigning a Boolean to a sys_refrcursor parameter, may there's more to it.

I suggest you run this query to see what other errors the compiler has spotted.

```
select * from user_errors 
where name = 'SP_COMMS_UPDATE_STG'
```

IDEs like Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer and Oracle SQL Developer will do this for us automatically (in Orcale SQL Developer you need to click on the **Errors** tab) but it doesn't do any harm to know the explicit query.

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;

Comment: Well that error message indicates a **syntax error**. But it's impossible to say how to fix it without the line number or code to which it references.